# Contenteditable on IOS: control/prevent selection toolbar?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, contenteditable

I've got my own toolbar for contenteditable. On ipad the system generates its own pop-up toolbar when text is selected. This prevents the use of my toolbar, which has options not included in the built-in one.

Is there a way to disable/hide/edit the behaviour of this toolbar?

[image]

Comment: I am also interested if you come up with a solution.

Comment: Nope, nothing yet, other than making sure your own toolbar is below the editable area.

Comment: any new update on how to resolve beside repositioning the toolbar ?

Comment: Related: is there feature detection for this so that we can reposition if needed?

Comment: You'd detect that the browser is ios/safari. Only IOS devices have this feature.

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane, and Androids have that type of feature!

Answer (score 6):

I reported this issue in the [WebKit issue tracker, bug 147406](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=147406) as it seems there is no way to control this.

The impossibility to hide the toolbar completely is one problem, another one is that BIU (Bold/Italic/Underline) should not be always enabled as not always such formatting is enabled in a wysiwyg editor. For example in CKEditor the list of accepted tags can be configured via [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf)), so if one disables `<b>/<strong>`, `B` should not appear in the contextual toolbar as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the following style to your content editable div: `-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;`.

Note this has the byproduct of preventing "ctrl+b", "ctrl+i" etc as well. This is probably a good thing.