# Native mobile context menu covers CKEditor

Tags: android, ios, ckeditor, contextmenu, hybrid-mobile-app

I’ve got CKEditor running on Android (KitKat & Lollipop) and iOS 9.  However, the context menu (the select all/copy/paste menu) on both platforms covers the CKEditor toolbar.  I was wondering what strategies people are using to deal with this?

Here are a few things I’ve tried:

1. **-webkit-touch-callout: none;** This didn’t work on Android or iOS.
2. **-webkit-user-select: none;** This disabled the context menu, but only because it disabled selection.  I want selection - I just don’t want the native context menu.
3. I’ve played with **config.floatSpacePinnedOffsetY** and friends to try and offset the toolbar, but I haven’t found offsets that work well for all scenarios.
4. Since our app is a hybrid app, I investigated subclassing the Android and iOS WebView’s to disable the context menu natively.  I haven’t had any luck yet making this work.

Screenshots:

[iOS context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4cdT.png)

[Android context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEbOB.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Contenteditable on IOS: control/prevent selection toolbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693315/contenteditable-on-ios-control-prevent-selection-toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

It's a browser bug/limitation. See [WebKit issue #147406](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=147406) - feel free to bring your problem there too. I believe it is kinda duplicate of [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693315/contenteditable-on-ios-control-prevent-selection-toolbar) too.